# Rails Active admin path disappeared

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

If I have three resources, 
when I declare a belongs_to in one resource, it works well

```html
ActiveAdmin.register Order
ActiveAdmin.register Material do
  belongs_to :order
end
```

this generates path below

```
batch_action_admin_order_materials POST       /admin/orders/:order_id/materials/batch_action(.:format) admin/materials#batch_action
             admin_order_materials GET        /admin/orders/:order_id/materials(.:format)              admin/materials#index
                                   POST       /admin/orders/:order_id/materials(.:format)              admin/materials#create
          new_admin_order_material GET        /admin/orders/:order_id/materials/new(.:format)          admin/materials#new
         edit_admin_order_material GET        /admin/orders/:order_id/materials/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/materials#edit
              admin_order_material GET        /admin/orders/:order_id/materials/:id(.:format)          admin/materials#show
                                   PATCH      /admin/orders/:order_id/materials/:id(.:format)          admin/materials#update
                                   PUT        /admin/orders/:order_id/materials/:id(.:format)          admin/materials#update
                                   DELETE     /admin/orders/:order_id/materials/:id(.:format)          admin/materials#destroy
```

but, when I add set the same resource belongs to another resource, the path above all disappeared, instead it generates path below

```html
ActiveAdmin.register Supplier
ActiveAdmin.register Material do
   belongs_to :supplier
end



batch_action_admin_supplier_materials POST       /admin/suppliers/:supplier_id/materials/batch_action(.:format) admin/materials#batch_action
             admin_supplier_materials GET        /admin/suppliers/:supplier_id/materials(.:format)              admin/materials#index
                                      POST       /admin/suppliers/:supplier_id/materials(.:format)              admin/materials#create
          new_admin_supplier_material GET        /admin/suppliers/:supplier_id/materials/new(.:format)          admin/materials#new
         edit_admin_supplier_material GET        /admin/suppliers/:supplier_id/materials/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/materials#edit
              admin_supplier_material GET        /admin/suppliers/:supplier_id/materials/:id(.:format)          admin/materials#show
                                      PATCH      /admin/suppliers/:supplier_id/materials/:id(.:format)          admin/materials#update
                                      PUT        /admin/suppliers/:supplier_id/materials/:id(.:format)          admin/materials#update
                                      DELETE     /admin/suppliers/:supplier_id/materials/:id(.:format)          admin/materials#destroy
```

I hope to have both of these path and do not want them disappear.
Any one can help, thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's hard to figure out what you mean... can you please expand upon "does not work well"? Can you please explain: what you observe, and what you expected to see instead, also any actual error message(s) that you received?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that you are writing `ActiveAdmin.register Material` twice - and the second one is overwriting the first one.

(also not you should use lower case for the belongs_to line)

Instead of writing it twice, write it once with both `belongs_to` inside it  eg:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order
ActiveAdmin.register Supplier
ActiveAdmin.register Material do
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :supplier
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wrote the first `ActiveAdmin.register Material` in order.rb and the second in supplier.rb. So, where shall I put the code you mentioned ?  PS: The relationship between order and material is one to many, supplier and material also one to many. No direct relationship between order and material.

Comment: I'd put the first line in order, the second line in supplier and the rest in a new file called material

Comment: Hi Taryn, thanks  again. I tried your solution, still have two problems. One, after I move `ActiveAdmin.register Material` out to material.rb. The page show an error `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Admin::Orders#index`  `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/materials"} missing required keys: [:order_id]` `raise ActionController::UrlGenerationError, message`

Comment: Two, after I move Material out, it still only generate one set of path, eg: if `belongs_to :order   belongs_to :supplier` , then only generate admin_supplier_materials to material index action. It always **only generate path for the last belongs_to relationship**. I hope to have them both

Comment: hmmm - what are the paths that you eventually want to be able to use? I looked at the doco... : http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#belongs-to I'm not sure how it would work if there are multiple paths for the same thing. I mean you and I know you want both sets of paths... but maybe it's getting confused and trying to figure out how to do some kind of combination path that uses both of them... I dunno.

Comment: Many thanks. Maybe the gem do not support this feature. This problem confused me three days. I am thinking about whether I should build the system by myself, instead of using Active admin.  I am a beginner of ROR, Active admin show me many great rails features and let me know more gems like formtastic and cancan. I want the system be more extendable, maybe it is better to it without this gem.

Answer (score 0):

May be You can try renaming resource: [Rename Resource](http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#rename-the-resource)

So your material.rb would conatin:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Material do
  belongs_to :order
end
```

And you can create new file supplier_materials.rb which will contain:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Material, as: "Supplier Material" do
  belongs_to :supplier
end
```

This would work as two separate resources.